# JavaScript Collision Detection bug

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, collision-detection

Hello to all who are reading this post
In trying to make Mario type of game but I have some collision bug 
maybe someone can explain to me whats is incorrect and how to fix it

Collision part there while be hard coded value
I can't jump on box correctly is hard to explain if it's not hard just cache js fiddle link!

controls on arrow's space jump the issues is with jumping
Game logic

[Game logic Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ard4.png)

```js
var hero = {
    X: 200,
    Y: 450,
    gravity: 0.05,
    gravitySpeed: 0,
    speed: 2,
    height: 50,
    width: 50

}


var box = {
    X: 300,
    Y: 450,
    height: 50,
    width: 50
}
var map = {
    gravity: 0.5,
    groundY: 350

}
var optiones = {
    crashWith: function (otherobj) {
        var myleft = hero.X;
        var myright = hero.X + (50);
        var mytop = hero.Y;
        var mybottom = hero.Y + (50);

        var otherleft = box.X;
        var otherright = box.X + (50);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = box.Y + (50);
        var crash = true;
//Hard coded values
        var Y = 450,
            X = 300,
            w = 50,
            h = 50
        // not tuching
        if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
            (mytop > otherbottom) ||
            (myright < otherleft) ||
            (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
            //            console.log("dont tuch")
            hero.Y += hero.gravitySpeed;
            hero.gravitySpeed += hero.gravity;
        } else {
            // collision rules
            if (mytop >= othertop && othertop < otherbottom) {
                if (hero.X <= X) {
                    hero.X = X - hero.width
                } else if (hero.X > X) {
                    hero.X = X + hero.width
                }
            } else if (hero.X >= X && hero.X <= X + w) {

                if (hero.Y <= Y) {

                    hero.Y = Y - hero.height
                } else if (hero.Y >= Y) {
                    hero.Y = Y + hero.height
                }
            }


        }
```

And here while be a full code to look at or play whit it on js fiddle
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4vfmdco/)

Comment: Your snippet appears to work, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can go thro elements when I'm jumping

Comment: Replace box with otherobj

Comment: I little bit don't understand how it while help

Comment: It may not help, but it looked like a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your function says:

```
function crashwith(otherobj){}
```

But inside you say

```
othertop=box.y;
```

Youre not checking if the hero crashes with the passed object, but with a box. Thats not what i think the function should do. I think you want:

```
othertop=otherobj.y;
```

Also your crash function must be

```
       if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
        (mytop > otherbottom) ||
        (myright < otherleft) ||
        (myleft > otherright)) {
        Alert("crash");
        }
```

Your logic is the other way round

Comment: ok I while play around but I'm still stuck I just updated the post!! thank you for replay

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm trying something like this

```
        if(myright >= otherleft && mybottom > othertop &&myleft < otherright){
        console.log("R______")
        hero.X = otherleft - hero.width
    }
    if(myleft <= otherright && mybottom > othertop && myright > otherleft){
        console.log("L______")
        hero.X = otherleft + hero.width
    }
```

Comment: ok now I really don't understand how to change my logic can you help..?

Answer (score 0):

How i understand i don't need this part

```
       if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
        (mytop > otherbottom) ||
        (myright < otherleft) ||
        (myleft > otherright)) {
        crash = false;
```

Comment: Your code works for a normal mathematical graph, but the canvas has the y axis going down. So the higher the y the lower is the box.(may i produced a bit chaos in my brain, but i think its like that)

Comment: please check the game logic img i jus add it to post

Comment: Jep ive got that. I was confused with the y axis myself, so your code is right as far as i understand

Comment: ok but still there is the bug when you touch the left side of the box press jump(space button) and then press right arrow